# Add VBA macro to excel using javascript or python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, excel, exceljs

Anyone here worked on adding a VBA macro to an existing excel sheet using python or Javascript??

I have an application build on top of HapiJs, and have a requirement to download an excel, which consists of a VBA macro

We used exceljs library on node to generate the excel sheet from data, unfortunately it does not support .xlsm format.

Also tried to xlsx(SheetJS) library which supports .xlsm but it’s does not support cell styling as of now.

Finally I also manually unzipped a macro enabled excel and copied stuff into our excel but even that fails.

Also tried using Various python libraries but had no luck. (openpyxl, xlrd, xlsxwriter etc.)

Comment: Have you checked: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-easiest-way-to-use-Python-in-Excel-as-a-full-replacement-for-VBA ?

Comment: @FieryCat I want to use VBA Macro not replace it with python. Thanks for the suggestion though.